# Java Trusting ssl CA

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, axis

I guess I am out of ideas here.

I am trying to consume a web service in java which has an ssl certificate.

I createt a a keystore file in which I have added the certificate. The file lies in my project folder.

I imported it using:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "folder\\keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "SECRET");
```

Apparently, the web service call checks the keystore because when giving a wrong path to the file the application throws an exception when invoking the WS, not when setting the system property.

Anyway, when giving the correct path to the keystore file, I still get

> AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: (401)Authorization Required

Someone told me I had to trust the CA, before any of this would work.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'd say the error does not relate to SSL encryption. The web service is secured by other mechanisms beyond SSL (authentication), e.g. SSL Client certificates, WS-Security, etc. Ask the provider what to do.

Comment: This is not related to SSL certification.It seems that username and password is not accessible.please check username and pwd have full permission what you have passed.

Comment: The thing is, that I am able to access the web service using delphi7 by just supplying my username and password (and generating client stubs from the wsdl).

Comment: You must understand the exact authentication mechanism. It could be e.g. `WS-Security Username profile`, `HTTP Basic auth`, `Cookie based auth`. You must ask the provider, everything else is guessing...

Comment: As you received a SOAP faultCode: reply, your SSL is working perfectly, certificates and all. The issue you have is about authorizing to the AXIS service itself, not to the server's SSL mechanism.

Comment: So how do I configure my prxoy instance to use HttpBasic Authentication? My code simply instanziates the proxy, that was created by the AXIS generator and invokes (tries at least) its methods.

Comment: Ok, solved. At least, I learned about keystores. Might come in handy sometime. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the service uses HTTP Basic authentication.

The Stub that Axis generated (which extends org.apache.axis.client.stub), needs the following 2 lines in the constructor

```
((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) this)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "HTTPUSER");
((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) this)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "HTTPPW");
```

Thank ya'll for ya help.

Regards